# Upgrade Windows 7 Home to Pro (or Ultimate)

Tags: windows, windows-7

I purchased a new laptop which I’ll receive shortly…The operating system is Windows 7 Home edition.

I will want to upgrade (or change OS) to either Professional or Ultimate.

I am faced with the following options:

Option 1)
I’ve read about this new Windows Anytime Upgrade which will upgrade your current OS to another version provided you have a Windows Anytime Upgrade **Key**.

Option 2) 
Assuming I already have the DVD and license product key for Windows 7 Professional (or Ultimate), simply place the DVD and upgrade while providing the **product key**.

Option 3) 
Completely format the laptop assuming I have the appropriate DVD and **product key**.

My questions are the following:

> How is the Windows Anytime Upgrade **Key** different from the DVD
>   **product Key**?
>
> Are they the same?
>
> If I decide to go along with option 1), can I use the DVD **product Key**
>   or do I absolutely need this Windows Anytime Upgrade **Key**?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 disk product keys:

- Upgrade Disk
- Full Install Disk

Since you are already on windows 7, anytime upgrade is ideal to move onto another edition as its faster and doesnt require full program re-install.

Anytime is also cheaper than an upgrade disk.

Upgrade disk is really ment for people upgrading from a previous OS, such as XP or Vista

Comment: I’ve read that the version of Windows cannot be modified after installation. I have read several times that specifically, Home cannot be upgraded to Professional (or Ultimate) without re-installing. Are you sure it can be done?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. http://www.microsoft.com/windows/buy/windows-7-upgrade-to-professional.aspx It clearly says upgrade from: 'starter' or 'home', and they even have different prices

Comment: Cool. I always thought it *should* be possible (after all, you can upgrade from one whole version of Windows to another; even XP to 7 indirectly through Vista!), so I was surprised when I looked it up a while back and all the responses said it could not be done. Thanks.